# Crash when setting UIDatePicker date

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uidatepicker

I've got an app on the app store, and there's a crash some users are experiencing that I can't replicate - for me it works fine. The crash is caused by this line of code:

```
timePicker.date = editingEvent.time;
```

where timePicker is an UIDatePicker, editingEvent is a custom object, and time is an NSDate property. Here's the backtrace:

> Last Exception Backtrace: 0   CoreFoundation
>     0x3785029e __exceptionPreprocess + 158 1   libobjc.A.dylib
>     0x3535097a objc_exception_throw + 26 2   CoreFoundation
>     0x37850158 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 96 3   Foundation
>     0x398e62aa -[NSAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 86 4
>   UIKit                             0x3736be20 -[_UIDatePickerView
>   _setDate:animated:forced:] + 144 5   UIKit                            0x373742d4 -[_UIDatePickerView setDate:animated:] + 28 6   UIKit
>     0x3743d464 -[UIDatePicker setDate:] + 32

Any ideas - what am I overlooking/what could be going wrong? How might I proceed from here to find out where the bug could be?

Comment: difficult to tell without additional details, but i did a simple experiment where I set myDatePicker.date=nil and it crashed. So I would definitely look at cases where editingEvent can be nil

Comment: use the setter property to set the date

Answer (score 1):

Do like this,

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:editingEvent.time];

NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate *timeFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
timeFromString = [timeFormatter dateFromString:formattedDateString];
timePicker.date=timeFromString;
```